# browser not sending cookie to server from local host while sending from another origin

Tags: cookies, browser, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have an issue i don't understand.
I make an api call from a.b.com to a.b.com
In devtools I can see the request and I can see it contain cookie as expected.
Then I make the same api call from my local host to a.b.com and the cookie is not present.
As per my knowledge and online documentation search, cookie should be sent to server if it matches all its rules (domain, path, expires, etc.)

If so why the request is different for each origin?

We use CORS calls all the time.
In addition just to verify, I disabled Chrome 3rd party cookie protection.

Here is an image to provide more details:
[image]

Don't be shy to point me to good documentation on this matter :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons you cannot share cookies between two different domains. You cannot exchange cookies between localhost and a.b.com.

Comment: but the cookies are on the same domain as I do the call to. if that was correct than you cannot do CORS with data stored in cookies